# Recording not allow second time

Tags: android

I develop Recording audio app in which recording are store in sdcard.i got success record sound at first time but (like click on record button start recordign and click stop button it will stop) now problem is raise second time. wen i click on record button it will exit from app.

Here i have attach **recordign** file ::

```
package com.SaxParser2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


 public class AudioRecorder {

  final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
  final String path;
  final Random myRandom = new Random();
  String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());



  /**
   * Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of SD card).
   */
  public AudioRecorder(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);

  }

  public String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());
         int  strHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
         int strSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
         int strMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
         int strMonth  = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         int strYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         int strDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      path += String.valueOf(myRandom.nextInt())+""+strSecond+strMinute+strDay+strMonth+strYear+".mp3";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }

  /**
   * Starts a new recording.
   */
  public void start() throws IOException {
String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
    throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
}

// make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
  throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
}
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
}

  /**
   * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
   */
  public void stop() throws IOException {

    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
  }

}

**ListAdapter  ::** 

    package com.SaxParser2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity context;
    String title[];
    String description[];

    AudioRecorder recorder;// = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r");

    private static String mFileName = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title,
            String[] description) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return title.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        TextView txtViewDescription;
        Button record, stop;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.record = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.record);
            holder.stop = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stop);
            recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"+ position);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
            holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        holder.record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {

                    recorder.start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                    String s = writer.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    recorder.stop();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                    String s = writer.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add the logcat output here

Comment: recorder = new MediaRecorder(); add this line in start() and let me know what happen?

Comment: @user370305  `AudioRecorder recorder =  new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r");`

Comment: @user370305 i have update my listAdapter file please see it

Comment: you didn't get me. In your AudioRecorder class's onStart() method write recorder = new MediaRecorder(); and declare just private MediaRecorder recorder; at staring point before method.

Comment: @user370305 now i got solution. but now problem is that inside from list when i have click on second number list item and recording it, it will overwrite on same.

Comment: @user370305 updation which you said i have change it and update also in question. so please show it

Comment: @user370305 i think we are going right direction

Comment: and now your problem of "i have click on second number list item and recording it, it will overwrite on same" - it is because of  AudioRecorder recorder =  new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"); so you ahve to change at every new record like  AudioRecorder recorder =  new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r2");

Comment: so in  holder.record.setOnClickListener's onCLick() in try block after recorder.start(); every new record like AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"+position); and remove AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"); this line from staring of listAdapter class.

Comment: you are not releasing it's resources in adapter class

Comment: @user370305  thats not same name problem because i use randome number + date + time to apply name it

Comment: @LLango J can you please elaborate

Comment: had you try the changes what I suggestted?

Comment: recorder = new MediaRecorder();  i have change it. but for `AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"+position);` i have think previously but i need to add name as unique so i have applu randomenumber + time + date Combination

Comment: yes, you are right but here we are trying to solve your problem, for some time can you try what I said? just put AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"+position); this line holder.record.setOnClickListener's onCLick() in try block after recorder.start();

Comment: ok lets watch as respect to you

Comment: @user370305 i have also try it but cant.and i have aslo update those try portion in this question.please see it

Comment: some strange things i would like to mention is that :: when i restart application it will create new(each and every time when i start my app). but for listitem it cant create new

Comment: socond thing :: i show recoding file name as `r0526256965932011` where r0 is initial index of list now when i record 1st number index recording it will overwrite on it

Comment: now look at my answer. and its work for me..

Comment: my meaning is that file name is differant each time but it remove old one.

Comment: you put the AudioRecorder recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"+position); code line in convertview clause it should be in holder.start button's click method.

Comment: just look at my code, try to use it. and let me know what happen, I made only 3-4 changes in your code.

Comment: Please consider using [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) instead of comments for extended discussion.

Comment: ya sure i have try your code but now my url is not working so i am close for today can you come for communication tomorrow ? +1 for great help.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard i have firewall restriction to chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this activity class, check code its different from your try to use this **ListViewAdapter:**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Activity context;
String title[];
String description[];

AudioRecorder recorder; // here I made changes......

private static String mFileName = null;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;

public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, String[] title,
        String[] description) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;

}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtViewTitle;
    TextView txtViewDescription;
    Button record, stop;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.record = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.record);
        holder.stop = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    try {
        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);
        holder.txtViewDescription.setText(description[position]);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    holder.record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                recorder = new AudioRecorder("/audiometer/r"+ position); // here I made changes......
                recorder.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                String s = writer.toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                recorder.stop();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Writer writer = new StringWriter();
                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
                e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
                String s = writer.toString();
                Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
 }

}
```

**your AudioRecorder class:**

```
package com.SaxParser2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class AudioRecorder {

  private MediaRecorder recorder; // here I made changes......
  private String path;
  private Random myRandom = new Random();
  String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());



  /**
   * Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of SD card).
   */
  public AudioRecorder(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path);

  }

  public String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
      path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         System.out.println("Current time => "+c.getTime());
         int  strHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
         int strSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
         int strMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
         int strMonth  = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         int strYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         int strDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
      path += String.valueOf(myRandom.nextInt())+""+strSecond+strMinute+strDay+strMonth+strYear+".mp3";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
  }

  /**
   * Starts a new recording.
   */
  public void start() throws IOException {
String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
    throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
}

// make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
  throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
}
recorder = new MediaRecorder(); // here I made changes......
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(path);
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
}

/**
 * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
 */
 public void stop() throws IOException {

  recorder.stop();
  recorder.release();
 }

}
```

Comment: it s good solution thanks can you elaborate what is mistake made by me?

Comment: @Dr.nik - Your mistake was small, You have to initialize your AudioRecorder class on every listitem click so it became new file, instead you were doing only once initializing so your audio file was overwrite. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Re initialize media recoder when you trying to record again, try this changed code,

```
public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))  {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
      throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
  }

  /**
   * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
   */
  public void stop() throws IOException {
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
    recorder=null;
  }
```

Comment: have you used the above which i posted?

Comment: sorry for the delay. if media recorder stopped then should release all allocated resources from media recorder. when setting recorder=null all resources will be released.